# Fetch Location using google Api

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps, geolocation, expo

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of user location using [google api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview#requests)

I have tried doing this using the fetch method in javascript but I do not get any response. There's no error or anything.
The documentation says to fetch it this way:
`https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MY_API_KEY`

How I fetch it:

`const res = await fetch(https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MY_API_KEY)`
`const response = await res.json()`

When I first did it like above I got an error because it returned nothing which I found out after console.logging `res.text()`
I do not know what I'm doing wrong In the documentation they equally said something about including Request body but it's optional, So I have no need to include it. Please do you have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to send this as a POST request according to the documentation you linked. By default fetch sends a GET request.

To do that you just need to pass in the request type to the fetch function

```
const response = await fetch(<URI>,{method:'POST'});
const res =  await response.json()
console.log(res)
```

Comment: This is correct. I so much thank you!!!!! I have been on this for a long time now. Your a blessing